# Error while updating in spring transaction

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I have done something like below to save my object in database within spring transaction.

```
public void saveMyObject() {

    TransactionTemplate template = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    template.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
    template.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {

        @Override
        public void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
            someService.update(myobject);
        }
    }); 

}
```

I get the error as below while doing this.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

What could be a problem in my code?

Comment: This can happen when you have another transaction which is acting on the same data.

Answer (score 2):

It´s usually call deadlock and it´s means that another transaction it´s using an element that you want to get, but you have another element that the other transaction needs in order to release theone that it´s having right now, so both transaction are block each other. 
Better explanation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html